# Integral roots of a polynomial

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, roots

I have one doubt.
Suppose, $f_{n}(x)=a_0x^n+a_1x^{n-1}+a_2x^{n-2}+,...,+a_{n-1}x+a_n=0$ be a polynomial with an integral coefficients. If for some $n$ ( say $n=2 \ or \ 3$)  , $f_{n}(t)=0,$ where, $t \notin \mathbb{Z}$.
   Can I say that all the roots of the polynomial $f_{n}(x)$ are not an integral roots.

Here I want to prove that the polynomial is not an integral,(here $f_n(1) \ \& f_n(0)$ are not odd)

Comment: If you're asking whether a polynomial with a non-integer root can have an integer root, the answer is clearly yes: take $f(x)=x(2x-1)$ for example.

Comment: Is there any proof in the literature? for a polynomial with a non-integer root can not have an integer root

Comment: No, because it's a false statement, as my first comment demonstrates.